# list_filter in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

```
DECOM_CHOICES = (
    ('N', 'No'),
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
)

class Host(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True)
    decommissioned = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DECOM_CHOICES, default='N')
    ip_address = models.IPAddressField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hostname

class HostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Host Info', {'fields': ['hostname','decommissioned','ip_address']}),
    list_display = ('hostname', 'ip_address', 'decommissioned')
    list_filter = ('decommissioned')
```

**Now is there any way so that i can set decommissioned filter to `'N'` by default instead of `'All'`?**

Comment: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8851

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this by modifying the GET data in the request object before passing it to `changelist_view()`. Not elegant, but it works.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if not request.GET.has_key('decommissioned__exact'):
            q = request.GET.copy()
            q['decommissioned__exact'] = 'N'
            request.GET = q
            request.META['QUERY_STRING'] = request.GET.urlencode()
        return super(MyModelAdmin,self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

**Note:** I haven't tried this exact code here, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Is there any way to make the 'All' link working with your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using code almost exactly from a [Django ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8851), which has a workaround in the comment for setting the default filter value. At present there's not a particularly elegant way to do this.

As an aside - wouldn't you be better of using a boolean field, since you're storing yes or no?

Answer (score 0):

if ('HTTP_REFERER' in request.META) and (request.META['HTTP_REFERER'].find('?') == -1) and (not request.GET.has_key('status__exact')):

**Use this save condition instead of the given in the above sulution given by 'gerdemb' so that all can also be selected**